# USB Camera streams with very low brightness with motion

Tags: drivers, configuration, codecs, camera

Trying to make live view from USB camera. But it shows dark screen (Low brightness) but you can see things like - light, flashlight  :D I'm using `motion` package. Any Ideas?

[image: Example how it looks]